# White empty images after PHP upload and MySQL insertion

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload, ftp

I have created a PHP and MySQL script which successfully uploads submitted images via PHP to a folder on my server, and then adds the filename with extension to my MySQL database.

With an FTP program I can see the submitted image inside the correct folder on my server with its correct file size. However, when I type the file path of the newly uploaded image (http://xxxxxx.com/images/image.jpg) into my browser, I get a blank page. Also when I try to import the image onto a website, nothing shows up.

However, when I re-download the image via the FTP program onto my computer, I can see that the image is TOTALLY OK. What am I missing?

Excerpts of my code are below:

```
    <?php
 // getting current post id and slug
 $pid = $_POST['pid'];
 $slug = $_POST['slug'];

 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = '../company/'.$slug.'/images/'; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']); 

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $pic = ($_FILES['image']['name']); 
 $fileTmpLoc = ($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);

 $extract = explode(".", $pic);
 $fileExt = end($extract);
 list($width, $height) = getimagesize($fileTmpLoc);
    if($width < 10 || $height < 10){
        header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: That image has no dimensions");
        exit(); 
    }
 $rename = rand(100000000000,999999999999).".".$fileExt;

// check for correct filetype
if (!preg_match("/\.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $pic) ) {
        header("location: ../message.php?msg=ERROR: incorrect filetype");
        exit();
    }



 include_once "../database-connect.php";

 //Writes the information to the database 
 mysqli_query($dbconnection,"UPDATE companies SET picture='$rename' WHERE ID='$pid'") ; 

 //Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "../company/'.$slug.'/images/$rename")) 
 { 

 .... etc
```

What am I missing that it does not show up in the browser?

Comment: The only thing that I could think of is that perhaps you don't have the `GD` library loaded in PHP maybe. Or, perhaps, you use a CMS and it has it's own htaccess rewrite rules which aren't properly using the `-f` flag, and therefore aren't ignoring the directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the path is not what you think it is when you try to link to the image or when you try to open it.

Note that this looks very wrong:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "../company/'.$slug.'/images/$rename"))
```

This will add two quotes and two dots to your path, so if `$slug` is `some_company`, the path will be:

```
/company/'.some_company.'/images/123456789.jpg
```

Perhaps you don't see or didn't notice that in your ftp program.

Also note that you have an sql injection problem, you should switch to prepared statements with bound variables.

Comment: thanks, jeroen, will look into it. however, i SEE the image with my FTP client in the correct location, and if i copy the path url from my FTP client and paste it into the browser (the URL is correct), then it is just blank ...

Comment: @rainerbrunotte Strange, but perhaps the ftp client hides the special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was indeed the URL output structure. Have changed it, like jeroen suggested:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "../images/$rename"))
```

Works fine now